# Trying to combine two datasets where object key ids match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, object

I have two datasets and have been trying to combine them, but have no idea where to start. I am making two API calls and below is a small example of a response:

```
{
    early_game_items: {
        57: 16
        59: 60
        106: 1
        180: 54
        214: 28
        232: 6
    },
    late_game_items: {
        108: 1
        116: 1
    },
    mid_game_items: {
        1: 52
        102: 3
        108: 4
        116: 1
        193: 1
        194: 1
        223: 1
        232: 73
    }
}
```

The other data set is numbered from 1 - 300ish and is an object made of other objects. Below is an snippet:

```
const items = [{
            "id": 57,
            "name": "void_stone",
            "cost": 825,
            "secret_shop": 1,
            "side_shop": 0,
            "recipe": 0,
            "localized_name": "Void Stone"
        },
        {
            "id": 58,
            "name": "mystic_staff",
            "cost": 2700,
            "secret_shop": 1,
            "side_shop": 0,
            "recipe": 0,
            "localized_name": "Mystic Staff"
        },
        {
            "id": 59,
            "name": "energy_booster",
            "cost": 900,
            "secret_shop": 1,
            "side_shop": 0,
            "recipe": 0,
            "localized_name": "Energy Booster"
        }...]
```

I need to put the data from the second data set into the first by matching the key in the first data set with the id in the second. For example:

```
{
    early_game_items: {
        57:  {amount: 16, name: 'void_stone', cost: 825}
        59:  {amount: 60...
        106: {amount: 1...
        180: {amount: 54...
        214: {amount: 28...
        232: {amount: 6...
    }...
```

Thank you so much for looking this over! I am new to js and am really trying to learn.

Comment: What does the second dataset look like, is it an object with numbers as keys, like this: { 0: { id: 57, name: '', ... }, 1: { id: 58, ... }, ...} ?

Comment: @domenikk I'm sorry it was not written very well. I added more to the second data set. They are just objects within an object. I need to match the key in the first data set with the id in the second

Comment: There can't be objects (or any other values) without keys in an object, what you've written indicates they're elements of an array. Please check my answer.

Comment: i looked over your solution and I am getting undefined for item. It is finding both the IDs but is not saving it to the variable. Not sure what is going on. I tried to fix it but with no success

Comment: I've fixed the comparison from === to ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as another answer naming the datasets dataset1 & dataset2, and assuming dataset2 is an array of objects. If dataset2 is big array, this answer has better performance:

```
let result = {};
// key = 'early_game_items', 'mid_game_items', 'late_game_items'
for(let key in dataset1) {
    result[key] = {}; 
    for(let id in dataset1[key]) {
        result[key][id] = { amount: dataset1[key][id] };
    }
}
for(let id in dataset2) {
   for(let key in dataset1) {
      let _item;
      if(_item=result[key][id]){
         const { name, cost } = dataset2[id];
         _item.name = name;
         _item.cost = cost;
      }
   }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Lol, you just copy pasted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Naming the datasets dataset1 & dataset2, and assuming dataset2 is an array of objects:

```
let result = {};

// key = 'early_game_items', 'mid_game_items', 'late_game_items'
for(let key in dataset1) {
    const itemGroup = dataset1[key];
    let _itemGroup = {}; 

    for(let id in itemGroup) {
        let _item = { amount: itemGroup[id] };
        // find item by id, in second dataset
        const item = dataset2.find(i => i.id == id) || {};
        // get name & cost via destructuring
        const { name, cost } = item;
        
        _item.name = name;
        _item.cost = cost;
        // store in new itemGroup
        _itemGroup[id] = _item;
    }
    // store in result
    result[key] = _itemGroup
}

console.log(result);
```

If dataset2 is an object with numbers as keys, you'll need to modify the "find by id" function:

```
// find item by id, in second dataset
const item = Object.values(dataset2).find(i => i.id === id) || {};
```